# KOrganizer - can't create any item 'Select a valid collection first'

Tags: kubuntu, kde, korganizer

**Kubuntu 20.10**, When i try to create an item in **KOrganizer** (event or todo), I have that message when I try to save. (empty calendar field? and i can't change it),
but when I open settings>configure>calendars, I can see 2 calendars: *Birthdays...* and *Personal Calendar* - which is marked as default.
So what's the problem ?

Comment: Having the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04.  This just started, I've added events successfully before, and I haven't changed anything since then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well. I know this response is late but for anyone who finds this page again....

1. Go into the settings (which should be in the tool bar at the very top of the window).
2. Once you click that, scroll to the bottom of the options and click *Configure KOrginizer*, then a window will pop up.

   It will start in *General settings* which is where you want to be.
3. Next, in the left hand side of the window, near the top it will say *Personal, Save, System Tray, Calendars*.
4. Click on the *Save* tab.
5. Then there will be 2 options: *Be added to standard Calendar* and *Be asked which calendar*.

   Click the *Be added to standard calender* option.

This worked for me.

Comment: Nice answer, but difficult to read. Please edit it and include necessary spaces between paragraphs.

Comment: Just tried this and got nowhere. It doesn't even say what a collection is. It's almost like it won't accept any input from me. It just throws it away.

Comment: @Joe Same here... either choice (standard calendar or "be asked") has the same result.

Comment: same here on ubuntu 22, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

It took my boss and I hours to figure this out, but we finally did. The steps to resolve this are below, and the reason this issue occurs is because you deleted the default “Personal Calendar”. My recommendation is to not delete any of the defaults in KSuite applications.

Steps to resolve:

1. First uninstall KOrganizer:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge korganizer
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get autoclean
   sudo apt-get clean
   ```
2. Delete the following line from  `.config/akonadi-firstrunrc`:

   ```
   defaultcalendar=akonadi_ical_resource_0
   ```
3. Hard shutdown.
4. Power back on.
5. Reinstall KOrganizer:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install KOrganizer
   ```